# Strange TextInputLayout behavior

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I am trying to display an end drawable in my textinputlayout. However, the drawable covers the background of the textinputlayout in an unwanted manner (see image [Drawable obstructs the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tDAv.jpg)).

The same behaviour occurs when using an outlined style.
Another problem occurs where the suffix behaves the same way (see image [Suffix problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg1YQ.jpg)).

Furthermore, the error icon is hidden until there is text in the edittext of the textinputlayout (see images [No error icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ksuu.jpg),[Error icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPZzk.jpg)).
The error icon also displays the same strange visual behavior.

This is what my textinputlayout looks like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/locationTVLayout"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                android:hint="Where?"
                app:endIconContentDescription="Find my location."
                app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_location_searching_24"
                app:endIconMode="custom"
                app:endIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
                app:errorEnabled="true"

                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_location_on_24">


                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/locationTV"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.AutoCompleteTextView.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:completionThreshold="1"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tempInputTV"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/tempInputTV"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"

                    />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

My Material gradle reference is :

```
api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'
```

Comment: What is your app theme?

Answer (score 0):

Use `app:startIconDrawable` and `app:endIconDrawable` instead of `android:drawableStart` and `android:drawableEnd`.

Both of these go into your `TextInputLayout` and not in `TextInputEditText`.

For more reference, check this out: https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields

Comment: I am terribly sorry, i seem to have provided code for the wrong textinputlayout, i have corrected this error in my question. Following your suggestion did not provide a solution to my problems :(

Comment: Make sure your theme extends MaterialComponents like `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: I have yet to find a solution :( would be grateful for help.